# tar compression without directory structure

Tags: directory, filenames, tar

Under my current directory, I have two sub-directories:

```
dir_1/
   - file1.png
   - file2.png
   ...
   - fileN.png

dir_2/
   - fileA.txt
   - ...
   - fileZ.txt
```

When I tar compress the two directories by :

```
tar -cvzf result.tar.gz dir_1/ dir_2/
```

I got **result.tar.gz** but it maintains the directory structure. I mean when I extract the **result.tar.gz**, I got `dir_1` & `dir_2` again.

How can I tar compress so that the directory structure is not remained, which means when I extract the tar.gz file, I only get files

```
result/
   file1.png 
   ... 
   fileN.png 
   fileA.txt
   ...
   fileZ.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you can do this with the `-C` option.

From the tar man page:

```
-C directory, --cd directory, --directory directory
    In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.
    In x mode, change directories after opening the archive but before extracting
    entries from the archive.
```

This means that you should be able to run

```
tar cvzf result.tar.gz -C /path/to/dir1/ . -C /path/to/dir2/ .
```

to achieve what you want.

Comment: I got error "tar: could not chdir to 'dir1/file1.png'"

Comment: I am guessing you missed the spaces between the directory name and the asterisk (*). If we replace all spaces by underscores it should look like this: `tar_cvzf_result.tar.gz_-C_dir1/_*_-C_dir2/_*`

Comment: Then I got error "tar: dir1: Cannot stat: No such file or directory"

Comment: @user842225 That's because the directory paths are relative, you need to either prepend `../` to the second one or use absolute paths. Also you can't use `*` because it would expand to the list of files in the current directory, you can use `.` instead.

Comment: Yes, gilles is correct, that is why my example uses absolute paths. Using relative paths with `tar -C` tends to get confusing.

Comment: After years of using tar, I only just now learned you can use multiple -C /dir/path options in one execution.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU tar, you can use the `--transform` option to rewrite file names when adding or extracting them to/from an archive. With BSD tar or with pax, the option `-s` does the same thing.

To remove the leading directory component (so that `dir_1/subdir/somefile` is stored as `subdir/somefile`):

```
tar -czf result.tar.gz --transform '!^[^/]*/!!' dir_1 dir_2
```

To remove all directory components (so that `dir_1/subdir/somefile` is stored as `somefile`):

```
tar -czf result.tar.gz --transform '!^.*/!!' dir_1 dir_2
```

Comment: This would also work: `--transform 's/.*\///g'` See: https://superuser.com/a/813884/141314