# How to tar only files in a multiple of directories but not directory?

Tags: tar

I have three folders under the  Test folder.

```
Test ----> dir1, dir2, dir3
```

Under dir1,dir2 and dir3, I have lot of files. I want to tar only the files not the dir1, dir2 and dir3.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136724/tar-compression-without-directory-structure/136728#136728

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/tar-files-only-no-directories

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939982/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-of-files-and-folders-without-including-the-directory-it

Answer (score 2):

In `Test`:

```
pax -w's|.*/||' dir[1-3]/* | xz > file.tar.xz
```

would archive the files without their path components.

Note that the `dir[1-3]/*` would omit hidden files. For symlinks, the `-s` would also rewrite the symlink targets.

If you only want the *regular* files in there, and assuming none of your file names contain newline characters, you could do:

```
find dir[1-3] -type f | pax -ws'|.*/||' | xz > file.tar.xz
```

If the file names may contain newline characters, on some systems, you could write:

```
find dir[1-3] -type f -print0 | pax -w0s'|.*/||' | xz > file.tar.xz
```

While `find` and `pax` are standard commands, `-print0` and `-0` are not so YMMV.