# TAR Files: Move Files From Subdirectories to Main Directory

Tags: bash, tar

I've been trying to use this code:

```
find documents -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf documents.tar.gz
```

to create a backup of the directory documents.

The directory has the structure:

[image]

And I want to archive them into a single directory documents/:

[image]

But I fail to do so. How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: You should have used text instead of those pictures.

Comment: The `-maxdepth 1` expression means that find won't go more than 1 directory deep. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could hardlink them on a different directory and than tar

```
# find all files in directory named directory
find directory -type f | \
while read f;
do
    f2=`echo "$f"|sed -e 's/\//:/g'`  # replace / with :
    ln "$f" "directory2/$f2"  # create hardlinks in directory2/
done
```

This will create the following links

```
directory/file1 => directory2/directory:file1
directory/file2 => directory2/directory:file2
directory/folder1/file3 => directory2/directory:folder1:file3
directory/folder1/file4 => directory2/directory:folder1:file4
directory/folder2/file5 => directory2/directory:folder2:file5
directory/folder3/folder4/file6 => directory2/directory:folder3:folder4:file6
directory/folder3/folder4/file7 => directory2/directory:folder3:folder4:file7
```

Comment: `for f in $(command substitution)` is not a good idea because even a space will break that. That should be done with e.g. `find directory -type f -exec ./script.sh +` with `script.sh` being your code starting with `for f in "$@"` instead. Furthermore you should always use quoting: `echo "$f"`, `ln "$f" "directory2/$f2"`

Comment: Agreed @HaukeLaging I updated double quotes and converted from `for f in` to `while read f` so files with spaces should be handled fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way to do this is to create a new directory just as backup source and fill it with hardlinks. I hope the whole directory tree you want to backup is on the same volume.

```
> pwd
/path/to/documents
> cd /path/to/
> mkdir tar-documents
> mkdir tar-documents/documents
> ln /path/to/documents/file1
> ln /path/to/documents/file2
> ln /path/to/documents/folder1/file3 folder1:file3
[...]
```

If the number of files is high then this should be done by a script.

Afterwards you run `tar` on this directory:

```
> cd /path/to/tar-documents
> tar cvzf /backup/path/documents.tar.gz documents
```

At the end it may be useful to delete the `tar` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Find all `*tar` files in current folder and copy to `MainDirectory` folder or wherever do you want.

`find . -iname "*tar*" -exec cp {} ~/MainDirectory/ \;`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to archive a directory, having the identical file structure in the archive is the best practice for taking that snapshot. What you are asking for is the renaming of your files to include its parent directories succeeded by colons followed by the filename. However strange to me this is out of context, I did manage to get pretty close using the `--transform` option:

```
 --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
                         use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file
```

An example of this is outlined in [this stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136867/126716) *(Though be aware that it is not [proper `sed` syntax](http://gilmation.com/articles/regexp-keeping-parts-of-a-pattern-in-sed))*. Using `--transform` your command would be this:

```
tar czvf documents.tar.gz --transform 's/\//:/g' documents
```

Unfortunately, this did not have the desired effect, as it keeps your subdirectories in the archive but they are empty, and the files are at the root of the archive, not in the first parent directory.

*I thought I had a solution for you using `-C, --directory` option, but it would not be very dynamic, nor would it accomodate for maintaining the directory names of files in the new file name.*

The solution I did find is a hybrid of what you have and the use of the transform command:

```
find documents -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar czvf test.tar.gz --no-recursion --transform 's/\//:/g' --transform 's:\::/:1' documents/
```

*Also, in your question you name your file with the `.gz` extension but it was lacking the `-z, --gzip` option.*

Hope this helps,
Alex